# Gulp Copy Files not working on Default Task

Tags: gulp

```
// Gulp Packages
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['copyFiles']);

// Copy Files
gulp.task('copyFiles', function() {
    return gutil.log('Gulp CopyFiles...!');
    gulp.src('./source/*.php').pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```

I can run the above code as 'gulp copyFiles'.

But when I just run 'gulp' (to run the default task) it doesn't copy any new files across - any ideas why?

thanks

Comment: maybe default should be defined after all the required tasks?

Comment: You never reach the `gulp.src()` part, because of your `return gutil.log(...)`.

Comment: I know... so dumb.... lol... won't do that again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be returning the result of `gulp.src` instead of `gutil.log`:

```
gulp.task("copyFiles", function () {
    gutil.log('Gulp CopyFiles...!');
    return gulp.src('./source/*.php').pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```